# Blank page when removing all mentions of grid()

Tags: python, tkinter, grid

I've switched from .grid() to .place() in my program, so I decided to remove a frame that contained the grid widgets:

```
BackButtonR = Button(registerPage, text="Back", command=lambda: show_frame(Menu))
BackButtonR.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
Button2F3 = Button(registerPage, text="Find")
Button2F3.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button3F3 = Button(registerPage, text="Calculate").grid(row=6, column=1)

LabelTitleF3 = Label(registerPage, text="Calculate Buy Price").grid(row=0, column=3)
label1F3 = Label(registerPage, text="Enter Ticker Symbol:").grid(row=1, column=0)
label2F3 = Label(registerPage, text="Expected CAGR").grid(row=2, column=0)
label3F3 = Label(registerPage, text="Years of Analysis").grid(row=3, column=0)
label4F3 = Label(registerPage, text="Expected PE Ratio").grid(row=4, column=0)
label5F3 = Label(registerPage, text="Desired Annual Return").grid(row=5, column=0)

entry1F3 = Entry(registerPage, width=7).grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0)
entry2F3 = Entry(registerPage).grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
entry3F3 = Entry(registerPage).grid(row=3, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
entry4F3 = Entry(registerPage).grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
entry5F3 = Entry(registerPage).grid(row=, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
```

But weirdly, when I rerun my program everything turns blank. This shouldn't happen, since I've removed any reference to .grid(), so the program should be working fine with .place(). Here is my full code:

```
print(220+135)
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Account Signup")
DarkBlue = "#2460A7"
LightBlue = "#B3C7D6"
root.geometry('350x230')

Menu = Frame(root)
loginPage = Frame(root)
registerPage = Frame(root)
for AllFrames in (Menu, loginPage, registerPage):
    AllFrames.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    AllFrames.configure(bg=LightBlue)

def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

show_frame(Menu)

# ============= Menu Page =========

Menu.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

menuTitle = Label(Menu, text="Menu", font=("Arial", 25), bg=LightBlue)
menuTitle.place(x=130, y=25)

loginButton1 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Login", command=lambda: show_frame(loginPage))
loginButton1.place(x=85, y=85)

registerButton1 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Register", command=lambda: show_frame(registerPage))
registerButton1.place(x=85, y=115)

# ======== Login Page ===========

loginUsernameL = Label(loginPage, text='Username').place(x=30, y=60)
loginUsernameE = Entry(loginPage).place(x=120, y=60)
loginPasswordL = Label(loginPage, text='Password').place(x=30, y=90)
loginPasswordE = Entry(loginPage).place(x=120, y=90)
backButton = Button(loginPage, text='Back', command=lambda: show_frame(Menu)).place(x=0, y=0)
loginButton = Button(loginPage, text='Login', width=20).place(x=100, y=150)

# ======== Register Page ===========
root.mainloop()
```

Why is my program turning blank?

Comment: Perhaps it's due to the fact that you're still invoking `AllFrames.grid(...)`?
Also, if you plan on holding on to your Tkinter object references, you should instantiate your objects in one step, and place them in another. Statements like `backButton = Button(...).place(...)` will bind the return value of `.place(...)` to `backButton`, which will always be `None`.

Comment: To clarify what @PaulM. is suggesting, you should separate the declaration of your widgets from their placement, e.g.: `loginUsernameL = Label(...)` then on a new line: `loginUsernameL.place(...)`, because `place()` returns `None` and, as written, your widget refs like `loginUsernameL` will therefore always be `None` (which is probably not what you want!)

Comment: Thank you, I'll change that! What does it mean if place() returns None? What problems could it cause down the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `pack` and `grid`, these functions will normally adjust the size of a widget's parent to fit all of its children. It's one of the most compelling reasons to use these geometry managers.

When you use `place` this doesn't happen. If you use `place` to put a widget in a frame, the frame will not grow or shrink to fit the widget.

In your case you're creating `Menu`, `loginPage` and `registerPage` and not giving them a size so they default to 1x1 pixels. When you use `place` to add a widget to the frame, the frame will remain at 1x1 pixels, rendering it virtually invisible.

The solution is to either give these frames an explicit size, or add the frames to the window with options that cause them to fill the window.

For illustrative purposes I've changed the background color of the window to pink, and set the size of `Menu` to 200x200. As you can see in the following screenshot, the frame with the widgets is there, and becomes visible when you give it a larger size. Of course, one problem with `place` is it's up to you to calculate the appropriate size.

[image: screenshot with explicit frame size]

The better solution in this specific case would be to use the appropriate `grid` options to have the frames fill the window. You can do that by giving a `weight` to the row and column that the frames are in. Unused space in the parent frame will be allocated to the row and column with the widget.

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

[image: screenshot after configuring the weight]

---

Generally speaking, `grid` and `pack` are superior to `place` for implementing most layouts because they are able to automatically make all widgets fit into a window with very little work. With `place` it's up to you to do calculations for position and size, and to make sure that all ancestors are appropriately sized and are visible.

Comment: Thank you. How do I set the size of each frame? I thought root.geometry() would cover all frames but apparently not

Comment: @BluBalloon: you can configure a frame's size when you create it, or with the `configure` method, eg: `Menu.configure(width=200, height=200)`.  As long as you're only using `place` for widgets inside the frame, the frame will try to be that size. Though, the final size of the frame depends on how it is added to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` so that the shown frame use all the space of `root` window, otherwise the size of those frames are 1x1.

Also `Menu.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` is useless because widgets inside `Menu` are using `.place()`.